# AngularJS: Select options from list, NOT object or arry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, html-select

Trying to create a set of select options from a simple list, instead of an array or an object that would have keys.  All the docs & examples I find are pertaining to keyed data types.

```
$scope.numbers = ['tweedle', 'beetle', 'battle'];
```

Using the code below, the select list renders fine on load.

```
<select ng-model="fox" ng-options="item for item in fox"></select>
```

After you make a selection, it splits the selection value into a comma separated list.  Try selecting and item, then selecting a different item.

I'm sure it has something to do with the binding, but I can't put my finger on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/LR6DL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting the `ng-model` of the `select` to `fox`. `fox` is also what your options are set to, so your options array is being over written with the selected value (string) - which then gets split to letters to satisfy the `ng-options` directive.

Short solution:

Change your `ng-model` to `selection` and your input to `selection` as well.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LR6DL/2/

Comment: Right, but I'm managing the data in 'fox'.  So if I need to submit that data to somewhere(JSON API), I want fox updated to the current selection.  I think I need to make the fiddle more detailed to explain the use case.  Your answer does solve the problem in this context, though.

Comment: Ahh..hmm... perhaps cloning the current array into a different `$scope` would allow you to continuously use `fox`

Comment: That's sortof what I just figured out: http://jsfiddle.net/cJ6AC/1/  I copied the values of fox into something I could just use to make the options.